# Get the names of IDs from different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with a lot of data from a database. In the array, there are two fields called `teameinsid` and `teamzweiid`.  The query is a very simple one :

```
$spiel = mysql_query("select teameinsid, teamzweiid from begegnung", $connection) or die("Keine passende Begegnung");
```

What I need is to search in the database for the names of these IDs. The names are in a different table.

What I have now is the following:

```
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($spiel)){
 $teins = $tmp['teameinsid'];
 $tzwei = $tmp['teamzweiid'];
}
```

So I know the two IDs, but I don't know where to save the names. If I try:

```
$name = mysql_query("select name from team where teameinsid = $teins", $con)
```

it gets overwritten every time. How can I manage this?

EDIT:

Database Scheme:

Table Team : id, name
Table Begegnung: id, teameinsid, teamzweiid

Comment: Your query doesn't match your code... Where is the query that *selects* `teameinsid`?

Comment: I added the query but that isn´t relevant for my question. I know how to get the two ids.

Comment: in while the $teins should be array

Comment: will you expose your database schema. It will help get proper answers.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this, and it works if your query in $speil is this:

```
SELECT B.*, T1.name AS teamnameeins, T2.name as teamnamezwei FROM begegnung AS B
JOIN team AS T1 ON T1.id = B.teameinsid
JOIN team AS T2 ON T2.id = B.teamzweiid
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

You should use your code now like this:

```
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($spiel)){
 $teins = $tmp['teamnameeins'];
 $tzwei = $tmp['teamnamezwei'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($spiel)){
     $teins[] = $tmp['teameinsid'];
     $tzwei[] = $tmp['teamzweiid'];
    }
```

now

```
$ids=implode ( ',' ,  $teins);

$name = mysql_query("select name from team where teameinsid in($ids)", $con)
```

Comment: This only takes it once. One Id can be in my array more than once.